# VB6 WIA Module-Automation Error

Tags: vb6, wia

I'm trying to use WIA in an older VB6 program running in Windows 7 and when I run from source everything works great and I can import images.  When I run from the compiled version I get the following error:

Automation error.  The specified module could not be found.
(Error number 2147024770)

I found the wiaaut.dll in both system32 and SysWOW64 so I don't know if that is potentially causing a problem. I tried unregistering and registering both to no avail.  Any help would be much appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know wiaaut.dll is preinstalled in Vista and Windows 7, but this is not the redist version for XP that comes in the downloadable SDK, and it should not be deployed to those newer OSs.  perhaps somebody tried to run some application installer on your machine that forced the XP version into place blindly?

Perhaps try [How to use the System File Checker tool to troubleshoot missing or corrupted system files on Windows Vista or on Windows 7](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929833) to see if it can restore the original Win7 version?